# Missing workflow path when using ForEach activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am using the WorkflowStudio 2012 .NET4 from Microsoft

When I add "ForEach<>" activity drop "If" activity inside DClick on the "If" "Drop activity here"

Then the workflow path (in the top of the window) disappear and I see only the "If" there
I then can't get back to the main workflow

Note
  This append only with the ForEach<> activity

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Isacc along the top of the workflow designer do you see the sequence path it will look something like the following.
[image]

You should be able to alter the display by clicking back through the items.

Comment: I see it, but then after DClick on the "If" activity it is show only the "If", so I can go back to the parent activity